# How might I comment out with sed or awk a block of two lines (a unique line followed by an indented nonunique one)?

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, sshd

I wrote the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

wireless_state=$(ip l |grep "3: wlp" |sed -E 's/^.*state ([DOWNUP]{2,4}).*/\1/')
ethernet_state=$(ip l |grep "2: en" |sed -E 's/^.*state ([DOWNUP]{2,4}).*/\1/')

if [[ $ethernet_state == "DOWN" ]]; then
  sed -i 's/^Match Address 192.168.18.109/#Match Address 192.168.18.109/;s/^Match Address 192.168.18.112/#Match Address 192.168.18.112/' sshdc
fi
```

where `sshdc` is a copy of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. The tail of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks like this:

```
#Match Address 192.168.18.103 
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.18.109 
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
#Match Address 192.168.18.111
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.18.112
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

I want my code to comment out the whole block of two lines, e.g.

```
#Match Address 192.168.18.109
#    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

whereas my code so far comments out only the first line of the block, like so:

```
#Match Address 192.168.18.109
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

A line as `Match Address 192.168.18.109` is unique, whereas     `PubkeyAuthentication yes` is not, and there is also unindented `PubkeyAuthentication no` somewhere at the head of the file.  How might I accomplish such task with `sed`, `awk`, or any other GNU/Linux utilities? Please let the solutions in Python be outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least with GNU sed (the default for GNU/Linux), you can use an *address range* of the form

> ```
> addr1,+N
>
>     Matches addr1 and the N lines following addr1.
> ```

So for example

```
$ sed '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,+1s/^/#/' sshdc
#Match Address 192.168.18.103
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
#Match Address 192.168.18.109
#    PubkeyAuthentication yes
#Match Address 192.168.18.111
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.18.112
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. Inspired by your answer I also figured out that `sed '/^#Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,+1s/^#//' sshdc` does the job of uncommenting what have been just commented out and so restoring the original configuration.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`, you could match the `Match` line, append the next line from the input to the buffer, and then substitute in a `#` at the start of both lines:

```bsh
sed '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/ { N; s/^/#/; s/\n/&#/; }' file
```

Here, the `N` appends the next line of input to the buffer with a delimiting newline character to separate the two lines. The first substitution adds a `#` to the start of the first line while the second adds one to the start of the next line. I'm using `&` to re-insert the newline character into the buffer as inserting a literal newline with `\n` with non-GNU `sed` is not possible.

If the last/second line of the section always contains the string `PubkeyAuthentication`, you could also use a range address with a single substitution command.

```bsh
sed '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,/PubkeyAuthentication/ s/^/#/' file
```

You could actually replace that second pattern with just `/^/` if you want the range to run until the next line only:

```bsh
sed '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,/^/ s/^/#/' file
```

Comment: Thanks, `sed '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,/^/ s/^/#/' file` works fine. Inspired by your answer I figured out that `sed '/^#Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/,/^/ s/^#//' file` does the job of uncommenting what have been just commented out and so restoring the original configuration.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` using `getline`

```
awk '/^Match/ {$0="#"$0 ; print ; getline ; $0="#"$0 } 1' file
```

Or by setting a self-(de)activating flag:

```
awk '/^Match/ || b {$0="#$0" ; b=!b } 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box, the following will let you apply changes to as many lines as you like starting from the matching line just by changing `c=2` to `c=37` or whatever number you like:

```
$ awk '/^Match Address 192\.168\.18\.109/{c=2} c&&c--{$0="#"$0} 1' file
#Match Address 192.168.18.103
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
#Match Address 192.168.18.109
#    PubkeyAuthentication yes
#Match Address 192.168.18.111
    #PubkeyAuthentication yes
Match Address 192.168.18.112
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

See [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105) for more information.

Comment: Many thanks, it works fine. How would you then uncomment, i.e. do the reverse, what has just been commented out?

Comment: Change the regexp to `/^#Match...` and change `$0="#"$0` to `sub(/^#/,"")`.